# text editor to copy math symbols/notations and formulas

Tags: math-mode, pdf, unicode-math, copy-paste

i'm trying to copy some notes from a pdf(opened in document viewer) which contain maths symbols and notations, like, epsilon. i've tried texmaker, LeX, gedit(of course), with different encodings, nothing is working.

Comment: copying math from a pdf and getting usable text is more a feature of the pdf you are copying from than the editor you are copying too. It's still very fragile and only relatively recently been possible at all, so for most pdfs that you find you can not copy the math in any usable way.

Comment: There is always the possibility to take screenshots of some of the big equations and past these, but if the paragraphs contain inline maths (or even symbols) then I'm doubtful a copy and paste is possible. Some resources though also provide the underlying tex file used to make the documents (or are obtainable upon request). This might be a better option.

Comment: `mathpix` claims to do this.  I know little about this tool other than its own claims; I'd love to have a knowledgeable review for TUGboat.